# how many event receivers we can use for one SharePoint Document Library?

Tags: sharepoint

i want to know how many event receivers can we use for one SharePoint List or Document Library?

Comment: I am not aware of any limitations, are you thinking about a very large number?

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be a technical limit but you'd have to question your technical design if you required dozens and dozens of them.

Answer (score 1):

We Can Inherit Receivers from SPListEventReceiver and SPItemEventReceiver.

Definition

Event Receivers have before and after events.

The events relating to a site are:

```
Before
    SiteDeleting
    WebDeleting
    WebMoving
After
    SiteDeleted
    WebDeleted
    WebMoved
```

A class needs to inherit from SPWebEventReceiver.  The behaviour is defined by overriding a method for one of the above before or after events.  You can access properties that relates to the event that the feature is listening using SPWebEventProperties.

The events relating to a list are:

```
Before
    FieldAdding
    FieldUpdating
    FieldDeleting
After
    FieldAdded
    FieldUpdated
    FieldDeleted
```

A class needs to inherit from SPListEventReceiver.  You define the behaviour by overriding a method for one of the above before or after events.  You can access the event properties using the parameter SPListEventProperties.

The events releating to list items are:

```
Before
    ItemAdding
    ItemUpdating
    ItemDeleting
After
    ItemAdded
    ItemUpdated
    ItemDeleted
    ItemAttachmentAdded
    ItemAttachmentDeleted
    ItemCheckedIn
    ItemCheckedOut
    ItemFileConverted
    ItemFileMoved
    ItemUncheckedOut
```

A class needs to inherit from SPItemEventReceiver.  You then override a method for one of the above before or after events.  The event properties can be accessed by the local parameter SPItemEventProperties.  One of these is the list item.

Mr.--->RKMaloth